# Hive partition query is scanning all partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I write the hive query like below

```
select count(*)
from order
where order_month >= '2016-11';
```

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 5; number of reducers: 1

I am getting 5 mappers only it means reading required partitions only(2016-11 and 2016-12)

Same query I write using function

```
select count(*)
from order
where order_month >= concat(year(DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),10)),'-',month(DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),10)));
```

**Note:**

> concat(year(DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),10)),'-',month(DATE_SUB(to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())),10)))
>   = '2016-11'

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 216; number of reducers: 1

this time it is reading all partitions {i.e. 2004-10 to 2016-12}. .

How to modify the query to read required partitions only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive partition pruning on computed column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782664/hive-partition-pruning-on-computed-column)

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369488/hive-query-runs-very-slowly-when-using-variables-in-where-condition/33384954

Answer (score 0):

`unix_timestamp()` function is non-deterministic and prevents proper optimization of queries - this has been deprecated since 2.0 in favour of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_DATE`.

Use current_date, also no need to calculate year and month separately:

```
where order_month >= substr(date_sub(current_date, 10),1,7)
```